# PowerShell - Array selective copying

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

I'm still new and can't wrap my head around how to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated!!

I'm working with an arraylist with two columns: user, and type.

Some elements have the same user, but have different types, like so:

```
user,type
--------
user,1x
user1,2x
user2,3x
user3,1x
user3,2x
user4,1x
user4,2x
user4,3x
user5,2x
user5,3x
```

For type, the higher the number, the more "valuable". The goal is to loop through the array and copy users and types to a new array.

The criteria for copying: If a user is unique in the array, then copy the line (I already know how to do just that); if the user is not unique, copy only the line with the most valuable type. How would I do this? The output I'm looking for is:

```
user,type
---------
user,1x
user1,2x
user2,3x
user3,2x
user4,3x
user5,3x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compliment the helpful answer from [**Santiago Squarzon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon), I think you can do this without grouping and just using the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) cmdlet:

```
$datasource | Sort-Object Type -Descending | Sort-Object User -Unique

user  type
----  ----
user  1x
user1 2x
user2 3x
user3 2x
user4 3x
user5 3x
```

As per comment from [**Santiago Squarzon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) this will do a sort based on a (`Type` property) sting compare, to sort upon the integer values:

```
$datasource |
    Sort-Object -Property { [int]($_.Type -Replace '\D') } -Descending |
    Sort-Object -Property User -Unique
```

Comment: this can work as long as the numbers only have a single digit and would fail if there can be more than one: `0..20 | ForEach-Object { '{0}x' -f $_ } | Sort-Object` vs `0..20 | ForEach-Object { '{0}x' -f $_ } | Sort-Object { $_ -replace '\D' -as [int] }`. if you can add a note mentioning this I'll upvote

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have the data source in variable, an array of objects with 2 properties, using this as an example:

```bash
$datasource = @'
user,type
user,1x
user1,2x
user2,3x
user3,1x
user3,2x
user4,1x
user4,2x
user4,3x
user5,2x
user5,3x
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

You can accomplish this task first by grouping the objects by `user`, this gives us unique records. Then for each group you need to sort by their number, for this you can use `Sort-Object` with a *calculated expression* that removes anything that is not numeric leaving us with the numbers then you can convert that string having a number into an integer, and lastly, if sorting *descending* you would output the **first record** or if sorting *ascending* you would output the **last recod**:

```bash
$datasource | Group-Object user | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.type -replace '\D' -as [int] } -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Output for this example would become:

```
user  type
----  ----
user  1x
user1 2x
user2 3x
user3 2x
user4 3x
user5 3x
```

Comment: Nice! For PS 7, this might be a shorter solution: `$datasource | Sort-Object { $_.type -replace '\D' -as [int] } -Desc | Sort-Object user -Unique -Stable`. Note that on PowerShell 5, without support for `-Stable`, it outputs the wrong `type` for `user5`. On PS7, it seems to work even without `-Stable`, but that might just be luck with this particular dataset.